# Debian packaged python does not latest scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, raspberry-pi, debian

My python program depends on scikit-learn - when I run this on ubuntu I get an an error

```
sklearn/base.py:299: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator MultinomialNB from version 1.3.0 when using version 1.2.1
```

I then reinstalled the package with

```
pip3 install scikit-learn==1.3.0
```

This works perfectly.

Now I run this on RaspberryPi 5, which runs a version of Debian bookworm, (*Linux ha 6.1.0-rpi7-rpi-v8 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 1:6.1.63-1+rpt1 (2023-11-24) aarch64 GNU/Linux*).

I run into the same error, so I try `pip3 install scikit-learn==1.3.0` - this fails with an error

```
This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz
```

So I try `sudo apt install python3-sklearn=1.3.0` but this fails with `Version '1.3.0' for 'python3-sklearn' was not found`.

I then ran

```
apt-cache policy  python3-sklearn
```

and got this

```
python3-sklearn:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.2.1+dfsg-1
  Version table:
     1.2.1+dfsg-1 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main arm64 Packages
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main armhf Packages
```

It appears that the Debian managed python does not have any versions of this package after 1.2.1. Am I reading this correctly?

How can I get version 1.3.0 of scikit-learn on the raspberry pi?

Comment: Have you tried installing into a virtual environment?

Comment: The whole notion of virtual enviroment was unknown to me. Thanks for pushing me in that direction. Will attempt to do so and update this thread.

Comment: Installed a virtual environment - works perfectly.